# Writing an ANTLR 4.8 Listener

Tags: java, antlr4

I'v an ANTLR grammar file:

```
grammar Cql;

parse
 : ( cql_stmt_list )* EOF
 ;

cql_stmt_list
 : SCOL* cql_stmt ( SCOL+ cql_stmt )* SCOL*
 ;
 
cql_stmt
 : OPEN_PAR* expr ( ( K_AND | K_OR) OPEN_PAR* expr CLOSE_PAR* )* CLOSE_PAR* ordering_term?
 ; 

expr
 : K_NOT* ( field | literal_value ) operator OPEN_PAR* ( literal_value | literal_list | FUNCTION | dates ) (compare_dates)? CLOSE_PAR* 
 ;

ordering_term
 : K_ORDER K_BY literal_value ( K_ASC | K_DESC )? (COMMA literal_value ( K_ASC | K_DESC )? )*
 ;

operator
 : EQ
 | NOT_EQ
 | CONTAINS
 | NOT_CONTAINS
 | LT_EQ 
 | LT 
 | GT 
 | GT_EQ 
 | K_IN 
 | K_NOT K_IN
 | K_IS
 | K_WAS
 | K_IS K_NOT
 | K_WAS K_NOT
 | K_CHANGED K_TO
 ;

literal_value
 : STRING_LITERAL
 | IDENTIFIER
 | state_name
 | field
 | dates
 ;
 
FUNCTION
 : [a-zA-Z]+ '(' (.*? | FUNCTION) ')' 
 ;

literal_list
 : '(' literal_value ( COMMA literal_value )* ')'
 ;

keyword
 : K_AFTER
 | K_AND
 | K_ASC
 | K_BEFORE
 | K_BY
 | K_CHANGED
 | K_DESC
 | K_IN
 | K_IS
 | K_NOT
 | K_NULL
 | K_ON
 | K_OR
 | K_ORDER
 | K_TO
 | K_WAS
 ;

state_name
 : K_EMPTY
 ;
 
field
 : F_AFFECTED_VERSION
 | F_APPROVALS
 | F_ASSIGNEE
 | F_ATTACHMENTS
 | F_CATEGORY
 | F_COMMENT
 | F_COMPONENT
 | F_CREATED
 | F_CREATED_DATE
 | F_CREATOR
 | F_CUSTOM_FIELD
 | F_CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TYPE
 | F_DATE
 | F_DESCRIPTION
 | F_DUE
 | F_DURATION
 | F_ENVIRONMENT
 | F_EPIC_LINK
 | F_FILTER
 | F_FIX_VERSION
 | F_ISSUE
 | F_ISSUE_KEY
 | F_ISSUE_TYPE
 | F_KEY
 | F_LABEL
 | F_LABELS
 | F_LAST_VIEWED
 | F_LEVEL
 | F_NUMBER
 | F_ORGANIZATION
 | F_ORIGINAL_ESTIMATE
 | F_PARENT
 | F_PRIORITY
 | F_PROJECT
 | F_RANK
 | F_REMAINING_ESTIMATE
 | F_REPORTER
 | F_REQUEST_CHANNEL_TYPE
 | F_REQUEST_LAST_ACTIVITY_TIME
 | F_RESOLUTION
 | F_RESOLUTION_DATE
 | F_RESOLVED
 | F_SLA
 | F_SPRINT
 | F_STATUS
 | F_SUMMARY
 | F_TEXT
 | F_TIME_SPENT
 | F_TYPE
 | F_UPDATED
 | F_USER
 | F_VERSION
 | F_VOTER
 | F_VOTES
 | F_WATCHER
 | F_WATCHERS
 | F_WORK_RATIO
 ;

compare_dates : ( K_ON | K_AFTER | K_BEFORE )? dates ; 
dates : DATETIME ;

DATETIME 
 : ('-'|'+')? (NUMBER ('d'|'w'|'y'|'h'|'m')?)+ 
 | ('"' DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT (DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT)? '"')
 | ('\'' DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT (DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT)? '\'')
 | ( DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT (DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT)? )
 ;


NUMBER : DIGIT+ ;

WHITESPACE : ' ' -> skip ;

SCOL : ';';
DOT : '.';
OPEN_PAR : '(';
CLOSE_PAR : ')';
COMMA : ',';
EQ : '=';
STAR : '*';
CONTAINS : '~';
NOT_CONTAINS : '!~';
LT : '<';
LT_EQ : '<=';
GT : '>';
GT_EQ : '>=';
NOT_EQ : '!=';

K_AFTER : A F T E R;
K_AND : A N D;
K_ASC : A S C;
K_BEFORE : B E F O R E;
K_BY : B Y;
K_CHANGED : C H A N G E D;
K_DESC : D E S C;
K_EMPTY : E M P T Y;
K_IN : I N;
K_IS : I S;
K_NOT : N O T;
K_NULL : N U L L;
K_ON : O N;
K_OR : O R;
K_ORDER : O R D E R;
K_TO : T O;
K_WAS : W A S;

F_AFFECTED_VERSION : A F F E C T E D V E R S I O N;
F_APPROVALS : A P P R O V A L S;
F_ASSIGNEE : A S S I G N E E;
F_ATTACHMENTS : A T T A C H M E N T S;
F_CATEGORY : C A T E G O R Y;
F_COMMENT : C O M M E N T;
F_COMPONENT : C O M P O N E N T;
F_CREATED : C R E A T E D;
F_CREATED_DATE : C R E A T E D D A T E;
F_CREATOR : C R E A T O R;
F_CUSTOM_FIELD : C F '[' NUMBER ']';
F_CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TYPE : C U S T O M E R R E Q U E S T T Y P E;
F_DATE : D A T E;
F_DESCRIPTION : D E S C R I P T I O N;
F_DUE : D U E;
F_DURATION : D U R A T I O N;
F_ENVIRONMENT : E N V I R O N M E N T;
F_EPIC_LINK : E P I C L I N K;
F_FILTER : F I L T E R;
F_FIX_VERSION : F I X V E R S I O N;
F_ISSUE : I S S U E;
F_ISSUE_KEY : I S S U E K E Y;
F_ISSUE_TYPE : I S S U E T Y P E;
F_KEY : K E Y;
F_LABEL : L A B E L;
F_LABELS : L A B E L S;
F_LAST_VIEWED : L A S T V I E W E D;
F_LEVEL : L E V E L;
F_NUMBER : N U M B E R;
F_ORGANIZATION : O R G A N I Z A T I O N;
F_ORIGINAL_ESTIMATE : O R I G I N A L E S T I M A T E;
F_PARENT : P A R E N T;
F_PRIORITY : P R I O R I T Y;
F_PROJECT : P R O J E C T;
F_RANK : R A N K;
F_REMAINING_ESTIMATE : R E M A I N I N G E S T I M A T E;
F_REPORTER : R E P O R T E R;
F_REQUEST_CHANNEL_TYPE : R E Q U E S T C H A N  N E L T Y P E;
F_REQUEST_LAST_ACTIVITY_TIME : R E Q U E S T L A S T A C T I V I T Y T I M E;
F_RESOLUTION : R E S O L U T I O N;
F_RESOLUTION_DATE : R E S O L U T I O N D A T E;
F_RESOLVED : R E S O L V E D;
F_SLA : S L A;
F_SPRINT : S P R I N T;
F_STATUS : S T A T U S;
F_SUMMARY : S U M M A R Y;
F_TEXT : T E X T;
F_TIME_SPENT : T I M E S P E N T;
F_TYPE : T Y P E;
F_UPDATED : U P D A T E D;
F_USER : U S E R;
F_VERSION : V E R S I O N;
F_VOTER : V O T E R;
F_VOTES : V O T E S;
F_WATCHER : W A T C H E R;
F_WATCHERS : W A T C H E R S;
F_WORK_RATIO : W  O R K R A T I O;

IDENTIFIER
 : '"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
 | '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
 | '[' ~']'* ']'
 | [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9.\-]* // TODO check: needs more chars in set
 | '-'
 | [A-Z]+ '-' [0-9]+ // ex) KEY-###
 ;

STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ('\\'. | '\'\'' | ~('\'' | '\\'))* '\''
 | '"' ( '\\'. | '""' | ~('"'| '\\') )* '"'
 ;
 
COMMENT
 : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
 ;

LINE_COMMENT
 : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];

fragment A : [aA];
fragment B : [bB];
fragment C : [cC];
fragment D : [dD];
fragment E : [eE];
fragment F : [fF];
fragment G : [gG];
fragment H : [hH];
fragment I : [iI];
fragment J : [jJ];
fragment K : [kK];
fragment L : [lL];
fragment M : [mM];
fragment N : [nN];
fragment O : [oO];
fragment P : [pP];
fragment Q : [qQ];
fragment R : [rR];
fragment S : [sS];
fragment T : [tT];
fragment U : [uU];
fragment V : [vV];
fragment W : [wW];
fragment X : [xX];
fragment Y : [yY];
fragment Z : [zZ];
```

And I'm trying to write the Listener so that I end up for an input `projectKey = 'foo'` I get :

```
new AndCondition("projectKey", Operator.EQUALS, "foo")
```

How do I write the listener to cope with this?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear exactly what your question is. Are you aware of how to add attributes and actions to your grammar? If not, you should read one of the tutorials or primers on Antlr that deal with these things. Otherwise I suggest adding appropriate `returns` attributes and actions to create them.

Comment: I think I've got it now!

Comment: Please either post an answer yourself or delete the question to avoid confusing other people searching SO

Comment: @sprinter I'll post my answer when I've finished implementing the class - still learning how to use it, so I Don't want to misguide anyone with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a visitor class which extends the base listener to create my entities are they see:

```
public class CqlListenerImpl extends CqlBaseListener {

    private final List<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<>();

    private Condition currentCondition;

    public List<Condition> getConditions() {
        return conditions;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterExpr(CqlParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        this.currentCondition = new AndCondition(
                stripQuotesFromString(ctx.getStart().getText()),
                null,
                stripQuotesFromString(ctx.getStop().getText())
        );
    }
}
```